# Why am I not able to change the legend title for this sf object plotting?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis

I have a set of point-based data in a vector called "yield_annual_offshore_advantages," which correspond to a value of energy expressed in Watt*hours and can be mapped on to a pair of longitude, latitude coordinates which I obtain from a data frame called "totalityofsites". Using the text below, I am able to get the points to show up quite nicely and everything, but the legend has a title which I would like to change. Let's say I want to change it to "Hello".

What am I doing wrong in the code below? If I'm not mistaken, something similar has worked on other sites.

```
library(rnaturalearthdata)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
world_map <- ne_coastline(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
#ggplot2::ggplot(data = world_map) 
ggplot2::ggplot(data = world_map) + geom_sf() + geom_point(data = totalityofsites[1:20,], 
mapping = aes(x = lon, y = lat, color = (yield_annual_offshore_advantages/1000)), size = 3) 
  + coord_sf(xlim = c(min(totalityofsites$lon)-10, max(totalityofsites$lon) + 10), ylim = 
          c(min(totalityofsites$lat)-10, max(totalityofsites$lat)+10), expand = F) 
  + title(main = "Annual energy yield differences", legend(legend = "Hello")) + ggtitle("Annual values, in kWh")
```

Grateful for any help.

FWIW I will just place the output of the above here.

[image: What the above code produces, and why I need to change the legend title]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `scale_colour_continuous(name = "hello")` to your plot. Here's a full reprex with some made-up data:

```r
library(rnaturalearthdata)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1
library(ggplot2)

world_map <- ne_coastline(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")

set.seed(69)

totalityofsites <- 
  data.frame(lon = runif(20, -100, 100), lat = runif(20, -90, 90),
             yield_annual_offshore_advantages = runif(20, -2000, 2000))

ggplot2::ggplot(data = world_map) + 
  geom_sf() +
  geom_point(data = totalityofsites[1:20,], 
             mapping = aes(x = lon, y = lat, 
                           color = (yield_annual_offshore_advantages/1000)), 
             size = 3) + 
  coord_sf(xlim = c(min(totalityofsites$lon)-10, 
                    max(totalityofsites$lon) + 10), 
           ylim = c(min(totalityofsites$lat)-10, 
                    max(totalityofsites$lat)+10), expand = F) +
  scale_colour_continuous(name = "hello") +
  ggtitle("Annual values, in kWh")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks! Sorry, I never know how much data to add to these things.